# Creating a road with the Curve modifier

Tags: uv, subdivision-surface

I use the array and curve modifier on a Bezier to create roads and curved bridges. The road texture has to be tileable lengthwise so I have to UV unwrap beforehand. Since the texture is square I have to divide the road up into bits that are as long as the road is wide. Which results in a blocky look:

[image]

Subdivision does the trick, however I would like to get rid of all the unnecessary Tris:

[image]

The Planar Decimate Modifier messes up the UV in some spots. So far I either left the extra Tris sacrificing performance, or I smoothened the road manually. Is there another way? I can't figure it out.

[image]